# SQL Server : create jobs

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure, jobs

I need to create a procedure which repeats itself several times. Let's say I want to change a character's position in a browser game for 3 minutes from one place to another. Its coordinates change constantly in the database. I need it to be dynamic so that I can use this code to move the character to more places in a different amount of time depending on the parameters passed to the procedure.

How can I do it?

Does jobs solve the problem? If so, how can I do it with jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned that the coordinates change constantly in the database, you can have an update trigger that runs the stored procedure you have in mind instead of relying on a job. Let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: Can you give me more info :) ?

Comment: You can write an update trigger on the table that stores the coordinates that would call your procedure. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use the RAND() function to generate random coordinates, and a sql agent job to run the procedure throughout the day.